# Two week notice when this Monday (9/3/2018) is labor day

Tags: termination, notice-period, employer, exit-interview, exit-planning

United States location: If someone has a job that they need to start on Monday that's 2 weeks away (in this case Sept 17th), would a 2 week notice given on Tue (9/4/2018) count as a *traditional* or *conventional* 2-week notice? 
Note that giving notice on Tuesday would only make the employee available for 9 working days (until Sept 14th) to the current employer.

Obviously, one can give notice this Friday (31Aug) and that'd be fine for a 2-week notice. but the question is assuming that's not possible along with an additional risk of being escorted out right away.

Comment: Giving notice on Tuesday will mean it's neither 2 weeks nor 10 working days....

Comment: If there is a reason you can't do it today (Friday) and it might lead to you being escorted out then something else is going on. Most places don't throw people out for giving notice. (Also if try throw you out you won't need to fulfill the two weeks)

Answer (score 2):

Notice periods usually encompass working days only.

To aid, a look into the contract(s) and labor laws / regulations is a good start, ultimately union / legal advice is the best candidate to be safe.

Comment: In the US, things are generally less formal.  Most places in the US are "at will", so either the employer or employee can terminate the relationship at any time, so that's the law.  Two weeks is a common courtesy, and I've seen employee handbooks that offered benefits for two weeks' notice.

Answer (score 0):

If they're planning to escort you out today, couldn't they do that Tuesday as well? I'd just turn it in today. Today is a working day, and it would account the 1 missing day Monday. Usually they don't count a holiday against you but that is best to ask HR. US companies tend to give vacation pay outs of unused vacations but usually with the idea you do not take any vacation during the notice period and work the full 2 weeks. Since Monday is a company holiday, it's usually not held against you. So it is best to turn in today.

Comment: Tree question is why is today going to load to him being escorted out. There is something missing here.

Comment: In some companies, for some positions (usually involving sensitive material), the employer will want the employee away from the job immediately.  The nice ones count that as working through the notice period.

Comment: @DavidThornley Even then, why would it matter if the OP gave his notice today or later if the end result no matter what is that he gets escorted out? Being escorted out because you gave your notice seems rather bizarre and unusual. They usually wait for a replacement and if they can get that within 2 weeks, then they might just not schedule you anymore or escort you out. I can understand that.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, when its time-frame stated in weeks, that is what it is.
Week ends on Sunday, so two weeks from Tuesday its this and next week.

Also, holiday should count as part of the week, so first available day of that week, should count that week as whole

Comment: A work-week can vary by company.  Sunday is not always the 1st day.